# Как вернуть printы из php обработчика для xhr?

Tags: javascript, php

На просторах родимого интернета нашел подобную функцию для получения ответа от xhr, но ответ меня не удовлетворяет.

```
let xmlHttpRequest = function() {
                        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                            form.append("fil", upload_file);
                            xhr.open("post", "file.php", true);
                            var text='empty';
                            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                                console.log(this);
                                if (this.readyState === 4) {
                                    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
                                        //var r=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                                        //text=r.text[0];
                                        //resolve(text); // Вызываем resolve и передаем text в качестве параметра
                                        console.log(resolve);
                                        console.log(reject);
                                    } else {
                                        reject(new Error('Error')); // Обработка ошибки
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                            xhr.send();
                        });
                    };

                    xmlHttpRequest()
                        .then(function(text){
                            console.log(text);
                        }).catch(function(err){
                        console.error(err);
                    });
```

Так как у меня в php обработчике есть обработка ошибок, и сами ошибки мне нужно возвращать, они выводятся там через `print_r()`. Как это осуществить, или какие есть аналоги с условием на получения ответа в нужном мне формате? 
Формат:

```
if ($_FILES["fil"]){
  $sql00 = "SELECT `file_exet` FROM files WHERE id = :fil";
                $req00 = $dbh->prepare($sql00);
                $req00->bindValue(':fil', $_FILES["fil"]["name"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $req00->execute();
                $_SESSION['FIL'] = $req00->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  print_r($_SESSION['FIL']['file_exet']);}else{print_r('ERROR_0001'.$ERROR);}
```

Comment: понятно, что ничего не понятно. выведите ошибки в том формате который вам нужен.

Comment: @teran Изменил.